# Getting Values From Editable Column In HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an HTML table that I have included editable columns. If the table has 5 rows, the user will update all the rows for col1 row by row and then update all the rows for col2 row by row etc. As the user is updating the values in col1 I need to get the new values and put them in an array and run some calculations on the values. So for example when the user is in row 1 col1 the array will have one element, when they edit row 2 for col1 the array will have 2 elements etc.

Here is my table:

```
<table id="myGrid" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
       <th>Iteration</th>
       <th class="CalCol1" id="CalColHdr1">Vol1</th>
       <th class="CalCol2" id="CalColHdr2">Vol2</th>
       <th class="CalCol3" id="CalColHdr3">Vol3</th>
       <th class="CalCol4" id="CalColHdr4">Vol4</th>
       <th class="CalCol5" id="CalColHdr5">Vol5</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Volumes)
    {
       <tr>
          <td >@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RunNumber)</td>
          <td class="CalCol1">@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Column1)</td>
          <td class="CalCol2">@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Column2)</td>
          <td class="CalCol3">@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Column3)</td>
          <td class="CalCol4">@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Column4)</td>
          <td class="CalCol5">@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Column5)</td>
       </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I have a Change function that fires when the user changes the values in the columns:

```
$("#myGrid   tr   td").change(function (e) {
    var value = e.innerHTML;
    var i = 0;
    var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this)) ;
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    col++ ;
    alert('Row: ' + row + ', Column: ' + col + ' value:' + value);
    var vals = new Array();

    // This gets all rows for the specified column, excluding a "hidden"row at position 1
    $("#myGrid tr:gt(1) td:nth-child("+col+")").each(function() {
        var t = $(this).html();
        alert("value " + t);
        if($.inArray(t, vals) < 0)
        {
            vals[i]=t;
            i++;
        }        
});
```

This fires correctly and I can iterate through each row for "updated" column but when I do the alert("value "+ t); it always prints null  for t. i.e "value "  in the alert message.

The exception is the first column, if I use "1" for the variable col, then it prints out the value for the Iteration column just like you would expect it to. But I am assuming since the other columns are editable i.e. rendered as "html-input tags" it cant get the values?

When I inspect the page here is how the row is rendered:

```
<tr>

  <td >1</td>
  <td class="CalCol1"><input class="text-box single-line" id="item_Column1" name="item.Column1" type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td class="CalCol2"><input class="text-box single-line" id="item_Column2" name="item.Column2" type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td class="CalCol3"><input class="text-box single-line" id="item_Column3" name="item.Column3" type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td class="CalCol4"><input class="text-box single-line" id="item_Column4" name="item.Column4" type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td class="CalCol5"><input class="text-box single-line" id="item_Column5" name="item.Column5" type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
```

How do I get the values that the user has entered into to the editable column for all the rows in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using razor and Jquery is bit different.

If you check the HTML DOM element of the created cells you can see that whole new `input` element is created.

```
<td class="CalCol1">
  <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field          Colunm1 must be a number." data-val-required="The Colunm1 field is required." id="item_Colunm1" name="item.Colunm1" type="number" value="3453">
</td>
```

So your `value` is inside that input element. You have to access there.

so pass that DOM object to the loop like this `.each(function (item, element)`

Then get the value of each input elements.

Here is the full code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#myGrid tr td").keyup(function (e) {
            var value = e.key;
            var i = 0;
            var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
            var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
            col++;
           // alert('Row: ' + row + ', Column: ' + col + ' value:' + value);
            var vals = new Array();

            // This gets all rows for the specified column, excluding a "hidden"row at position 1
            $("#myGrid tr:gt(1) td:nth-child(" + col + ")").each(function (item, element) {
                var t = $(this).value;
                var inputs = element.firstChild;
                var cellValue = $(inputs)[0].value;

                if ($.inArray(cellValue, vals) < 0) {
                    vals[i] = cellValue;
                    i++;
                }
            });

            console.log(vals);
        });
    </script>
```

And I used `keyup` event instead of `change`.
Hope this helps.